# No value with Stripes IbanElement

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, iban

I try to implement the IbanElement from Stripe to handle payments. I implemented the IbanElement as it should be but when I call the element I get an object with the bank, etc but the value of the input field is undefined. Somebody ran also into this and knows a fix?
Thanks!

Comment: not sure ' the value of the input field is undefined' means. Were you expecting to see the actual IBAN the user entered? You won't, you get a token object `btok_xx` which can be used to securely pass the IBAN to Stripe and use it there, but the actual IBAN is sensitive so your code doesn't need it and doesn't see it.

Comment: @karllekko oh for real? Okay, I have wondered if I implemented it wrong and the value is not recognized. Thanks!